# One to many save no response (promises)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm stuck saving a object with an array of object Id. I'm using node.js with restify and mongoose.

I have an outfit-request with many outfit-choices:

**Model:**

```
const outfitRequestsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  maxCost: {
    type: Number
  },
  outfitChoices: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'OutfitChoice'
  }]
}, {usePushEach: true});
```

**Router:**

```
application.post('/outfit-choices', (req, resp, next) => {
      OutfitRequest.findById(req.body.outfitRequest)
        .then(outfitRequest => {
          console.log(outfitRequest);
          const outfitChoice = new OutfitChoice(req.body);
          outfitChoice.save().then(outfitChoice => {
            outfitRequest.outfitChoices.push(outfitChoice._id);
            outfitRequest.save()
              .then(outfitRequestNew => {
                console.log(outfitRequestNew);
                this.render(resp, next);
              })
              .catch(next);

          }).catch(next);

        })
        .catch(next);
    });
```

**Render method:**

```
render(response: restify.Response, next: restify.Next) {
    return (document) => {
      if (document) {
        this.emit('beforeRender', document);
        response.json(document);
      } else {
        response.send(404);
      }

      return next();
    }
  }
```

[Restlet screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMzrU.png)

It keeps in a loop, but the record is saved in the db

[DB screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STekL.png)

I think that is a problem with chained promises, but I can't find out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it like this, I returned the last promise and put the `print` in a `.then`

```
 application.post('/outfit-choices', (req, resp, next) => {
          OutfitRequest.findById(req.body.outfitRequest)
            .then(outfitRequest => {
              const outfitChoice = new OutfitChoice(req.body);
              outfitChoice.save()
                .then(outfitChoice => {
                outfitRequest.outfitChoices.push(outfitChoice._id);
                return outfitRequest.save()
              })
            .then(this.render(resp, next))
            .catch(next);

            })
            .catch(next);
        });
```